# Why is the output of this code is 4?

Tags: c, string, sizeof

I am using sizeof function to calculate the size of a string.
It should have printed 2.But why 4?
Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{       
    char *b = "ab";

    printf(" %d ",sizeof(b));
   //printf("%s ",b);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on your platform pointers are 4 bytes. Or 32bit if you prefer.

**NOTE**: Using `void main()` as a signature for `main()` indicates that you are studying [c](/questions/tagged/c) from an old book probably, be careful!

Comment: Thanks@iharob.I got it.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is a keyword, not a function, and it tells you the size of a variable in bytes. The variable `b` is a pointer, and its size (on your system) is 4 bytes. If you want the length of a string, use the `strlen` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *b = "ab";
```

In your case, `b` is a pointer to a read-only string literal in the file. Pointers in your case have a size of 4 in your system.

If you want to find out lenght, you can use `strlen()` to do so.

Sizeof returns the size of the variable you pass to it in bytes.

Fun fact: You can even print the pointer!

```
printf("%p\n",b);
```

An example for an output would be:

> 0x8048555

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
 char str[]="asdas";
 printf("%d  ",sizeof(str));
}

Comment: @a874 `char str[] = "asdas";` means str is now a char array filled with `{'a','s','d','a','s','\0'}`. Every C string has a \0 terminator.

Comment: @ Magisch   That i know,but you wrote "Sizeof returns the size of the variable you pass to it in bytes"  ,then sizeof(str) should have printed a value equal to 48 because size of a char is 8 bytes on a 64-bit platform

Comment: @a874 You passed str, which is a char array. sizeof() will print the size of this array. Before you passed a pointer, which is not an array. in that case sizeof() printed the size of the pointer. Pointer =! array